# Javascript getting data undefined on console when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript

I have this data:

```
{
   "id":"01",
   "new":0,
   "closed":0,
   "locked":0,
   "subhere":[
      {
         "id":"123",
         "subname":"somename"
      }
```

...etc...

In the console log I'm getting this to show (See comments):

```
console.log('Level 1 ID: ' + obj.id); //This works!
console.log('Level 1 Closed ' + obj.closed); //This works!
console.log('Level 1 Locked ' + obj.locked); //This works!
console.log('Level 2 Subhere ID ' + obj.subhere.id); //This returns Undefined!
```

The last console.log is giving me Undefined but I don't see what the problem is...why?

Any ideas on why I'm getting Undefined on the last one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `obj.subhere` is an array so `obj.subhere.id` will be `undefined`. You need to get array element first which is the object.

```
console.log('Level 2 Subhere ID ' + obj.subhere[0].id)
//---------------------------------------------^^^----
```

```js
var obj = {
  "id": "01",
  "new": 0,
  "closed": 0,
  "locked": 0,
  "subhere": [{
    "id": "123",
    "subname": "somename"
  }]
};

console.log('Level 2 Subhere ID ' + obj.subhere[0].id)
```

Answer (score 5):

`subhere` is an array - and you're referring to it as an object.

Hence it should be rather:

```
console.log(obj.subhere[0].id);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use this

```
 console.log('Level 2 Subhere ID ' + obj.subhere[0].id);
```